# Getting connection failed error when trying to connect to geckowebdriver 0.16 and mozilla version 53

Tags: geckodriver

1495111288785   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:28965
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:28965 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MANAS', ip: '192.168.2.7', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Comment: can you add some description of problem?

Comment: First posts are hard.  Before making your second post read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).